# RxJava simultaneous remove operations

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm having an issue trying to understand, in a reactive way, how simultaneous operations to the same observable should work.

The scenario is the following:

I have a list of users and a remove button.
 Every time I press `remove` I'm making a call to the API: `UsersApi.removeUser`. It is possible to remove multiple users at the same time. Which means that multiple `UsersApi.removeUser` are happening simultaneously.

After each `UsersApi.removeUser` I need to make a `UsersApi.refreshUser` call

So in terms of pseudo code what I am doing when clicking remove is the following:

Presenter:

```
public Observable<User> removeUser(int userId) {
        return UsersApi.removeUser(userId)
                .flatMap(user -> UsersApi.refreshUser(userId));
    }
```

Fragment:

```
public void removeUser() {
   presenter.removeUser(userId)
     .subscribe(user -> {
        //remove user from ui
        // update number of total users
   })
}
```

The problem with this approach is that because of the asynchronous nature of the remove (multiple removes allowed) I cannot guarantee that what is reaching the subscribe is the latest one. The subscribe will be reached twice, one for each remove, and the user info might not be updated or the latest. Does that make sense?

What I want to happen:

1. Parallel/Simultaneous remove calls using a reactive approach (triggered by multiple remove clicks from the user)
2. After a remove call finishes, start the next remove call

Edit: What I would like to know is how to do/if is possible to do the solution I did (see edit2) using Rx operators.

Edit2: My solution for this was to enqueue the user operations (in this case `remove`) and emit, using a PublishSubject, when the `UsersApi.refreshUser(userId)` call finishes.

So basically what I did was (pseudo code):

```
private final PublishSubject<UserOperation> userOperationObs;
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<UserOperation> pendingOperations;
private boolean executingOperation;

private void emitUserOperation(final UserOperation operation) {
      if (!executingOperation) {
            executingOperation = true;
            userOperationObs.onNext(operation);
        } else {
            executingOperation.add(operation);
        }
    }

public Observable<User> removeUser(UserOperation operation) {
        return UsersApi.removeUser(operation.getUserId)
                .switchMap(user -> UsersApi.refreshUser(operation.getUserId))
                .doOnNext(user -> {
                   executingOperation = false;
                   final UserOperation nextOperation = pendingOperations.poll();
                   if (nextOperation != null) {
                       userOperationObs.onNext(operation);
                   }
};
    }
```

Comment: use Rx zip operator to detect when all the operations are finished

Comment: Each remove action is independent and can occur in different points in time

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You've described the problem but not what you want to happen.

Comment: Apologies. I hope I made it clear now.

Comment: concatMapEager does what you are requesting. It will process upstream in parallel, but concats results in order.
This article explains it well: https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2017/08/flatmap-vs-concatmap-vs-concatmapeager.html

Comment: ConcatMapEager achieves concurrency, but not parallelism, citing your article: concurrent, in-order, but somewhat expensive

Comment: Use `maxConcurrent` parameter of the `flatMap` function with your `userOperationObs` subject

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your UI click into Observable (eg. by using [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding)). After that, you could use `concatMap` operator to perform api call so it will start next network call once current api call is finished.

```
// emit clicks as stream
Observable<?> clicks = RxView.clicks(removeView)

// listen clicks then perform network call in sequence
clicks.concatMap(ignored -> usersApi.refreshUser(userId))
```

Comment: The problem is that each of the remove is a for a different user, meaning every remove starts a new stream. In your case each RxView.clicks starts a new obs and emits right away (because it's different stream)